# how to find certificates using keyusage values

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file, certificate

Experts, anyone know how to find certificates using keyusage values?
I'm searching for my personal store certificates containing with specific keyusage values. any help? i wasn't able to find any keyusage parameters that could be used in command line syntax.

The command find below did not work

```
certmgr.exe -s -r currentuser my | find "extensions" | find "keyusage"| findstr "KEY_ENCIPHERMENT,DigitalSignature"
```

Comment: I think you have to use certutil.exe to manage certificates from the command line.

Comment: oh is that any reason why doing so? my end goal is to get the certificates from the currentuser as certutil connects to localmachine which is not intended.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's exact duplicity asked at  StackOverflow [How to filter the certificate property values and export the certificate out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61811816/3439404).

Comment: Maybe I wrong, just thought that certmgr was the graphical and certutil the command line interface to do the same thing.

Comment: thanks. i have edited the main post of my new updates which josefz has comment here, i am struggling to find the command line syntax..can anyone help? it goes something like this for serial number in cert keyusage values.. do print the serial number,export pFX out..